# How should code for long function calls be styled?

Tags: python, coding-style

I'm going to use argparse as an example here, but I think it applies to a lot of things. Consider:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This is a description of how this program works.")
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title="subcommands")
parser_sub1 = subparsers.add_parser("sub1",
                                    description="subcommand 1 does something something something")
parser_sub1.add_argument("arg1",
                         help="Arg1 does somethign something something.")
```

And so on for 20+ ugly lines.

The add_argument and especially add_parser lines are, well, long, largely because of the help/description string. But I see no obvious way to shorten them cleanly. As you can see, indenting on a second line in the usual way only gains a few characters. Splitting the string over multiple lines would get awkward very quickly.

I ran into this issue while running some code through -m pep8, which complained about nearly every add_argument line being >80 characters. The root problem seems to be that the part of the line up to the open-parenthesis is just too long in itself to fit strings in afterward, even with a break-and-indent between arguments. There's a few ways I can think of to deal with this:

- Live with really long lines and ignore pep8
- under-indent the continuation line and ignore pep8
- use really short variable names to save characters (e.g. `ps1 = parser.add_subparsers(whatever)`
- alias what I can to save more (e.g. `psaa = parser_sub1.add_argument` for each block)
- Make a bunch of dictionary literals and unpack them into the function call with ** (but I for one find dict literals a pain to work with)
- read the function call arguments in from an external file in a less awkward format, probably YAML, then unpack (but then you can't tell what the code is doing without having to reference another file)
- ...something else?

Is there a known effective way to handle lengthy function arguments that, when written naturally, are jammed up against the 80 character convention?

Comment: I'd suggest splitting the long lines.

Comment: Unlike most languages, Python has an authoritative style guide which speaks to this question. Motion to reopen submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very much a matter of taste and opinion but here, have two!

- very little real code sticks to a strict 80 column recommendation. It's worth avoiding unwieldy, long lines but narrowly sticking to a constraint that originates from punch cards is silly. PEP8 addresses this as well:

> Some teams strongly prefer a longer line length. For code maintained
>   exclusively or primarily by a team that can reach agreement on this
>   issue, it is okay to increase the nominal line length from 80 to 100
>   characters (effectively increasing the maximum length to 99
>   characters)

- For something like this, making some kind of data structure that you express largely through literals and then shovel into the config calls, either through ** args or with loops is probably sanest. It makes all the text readable, inline and in one place, thus easy to edit. You should be able to end up with a blob in the middle of your code that looks vaguely docstring like.

Comment: A lot of people stick to 80 or 100 or 120 character columns. Our team sets a hard limit of 100 characters because otherwise it becomes very difficult to write code on any of our laptop screens. I was skeptical at first too but this to me is a perfectly valid eason for a hard character limit.

Comment: @AnubianNoob A limit is useful, both for readability and in order to be able to vide two windows/frames of code side by size. Getting too hung up on 80, though, is pointless. In fact, the PEP in question pretty much says so. I've updated the answer with the quote.

Comment: Oh yeah sure, getting hung up on a specific number for the sake of being that number is pointless. But it is good to have a strict limitation based on your team's preferences, and account for any new team members.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ('string literal broken across two lines '
...  'but it works because the parens keeps them together.')
>>> x
'string literal broken across two lines but it works because the parens keeps them together.'

>>> print('If this was already in the parens of an argument list '
...       'you are already in a context where string literal '
...       'concatenation works.')
If this was already in the parens of an argument list you are already in a context where string literal concatenation works.
```